# Can I resume Chapter 4 to complete the optional missions if I've already started Chapter 5?

Tags: ps3, dead-space-3

While playing Chapter 4, I returned to the Terra Nova ship after completing the CMS Greely optional mission, and it automatically started Chapter 5.  Can I still complete the CMS Brusilov optional mission from this point, or do I have to replay Chapter 4?

(Yes, I know I can simply try going back into space to the shuttle and attempt going to the Brusilov, but I'm not near my PS3 right now.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I did return to space and use the shuttle to return to the CMS Brusilov after having started Chapter 5, only to find out that its entry port is restricted to co-op play.  So it is not one of the main Chapter 4 solo-play side quests - and it is listed as a Co-op Mission in the Progress & Unlocks list for Chapter 4, d'oh!

I also confirmed that you can continue to find collectibles for chapter 4 after Chapter 5 has been started.